# Flask: are blueprints necessary for app factories?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to have several app factories(currently: one for development, and another one for testing). I am wondering what is the proper way to implement them.

Currently I use app object to register views(via `@app.route()` decorator). Do I need to start using blueprints(instead of app) to register views? Is there any way to have proper  app factories without blueprients?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

technically, you don't need blueprints, you can just register each route on your `create_app` function. Generally speaking that's not a great idea, and it's kind of why blueprints exist.

Example without blueprints

```
def create_app():
  app = Flask(__name__)

  @app.route('/')
  def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

  return app
```

You can have a single app factory for both testing and whatever else if you configure it that way. If you want to load different blueprints based on if it is in testing, you can do something like this.

```
from project.config import configurations as c

def create_app(config=None):
  " make the app "
  app = Flask(__name__)
  app.config.from_object(c.get(config, None) or c['default'])

  configure_blueprints(app)

  return app

def configure_blueprints(app):
  " register the blueprints on your app "
  if app.testing:
    from project.test_bp import bp
    app.register_blueprint(bp)
  else:
    from project.not_test_bp import bp
    app.register_blueprint(bp)
```

then `project/config.py` could be like this:

```
class DefaultConfig(object):
  PROJECT_NAME = 'my project'

class TestingConfig(DefaultConfig):
  TESTING = True

class DevConfig(DefaultConfig):
  DEBUG = True

configurations = {
  'testing': TestingConfig,
  'dev': DevConfig,
  'default': DefaultConfig
}
```

Make a folder for each blueprint where the `__init__.py` in the folder instantiates the blueprint. Let's say for a blueprint called `routes`

```
from flask import Blueprint

bp = Blueprint('routes', __name__)

from project.routes import views
```

then in `project/routes/views.py`, you can put your views.

```
from project.routes import bp

@bp.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('routes/index.html')
```

Answer (score 6):

For those who googled this question. You don't have to use blueprints. Just import current_app as app in your routes.py (or views.py, whatever) and you are free to go.

```
from flask import current_app as app
```

Also, you have to add this to the factory (the create_app function) to register your routes:

```
with app.app_context():
    from . import routes
```

Comment: This seems to solve my problem, but there is no documentation suggesting this is a good practice?

Answer (score 3):

**You surely can have application factory without the blueprint, but that often makes no sense.**

Assuming you have an application package called `myapp`. 
Here is your `__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    return app
```

Now we create a new `.py` file called `autoapp.py` （or `wsgi.py` or `manage.py` etc.） outside of `myapp` package. In the `autoapp.py`, you create the application instance and import the views from `myapp`:

```
from myapp import create_app

app = create_app()

from myapp import views
```

The import statement will link the `app` with your routes. You can import `app` in your `views.py` like this:

```
from autoapp import app

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello!'
```

The application structure:

```
myapp/
    myapp/
        __init__.py
        views.py
    autoapp.py
```

Comment: What about the circular import?

Comment: I put `from myapp import views` in the bottom of `autoapp.py` to avoid it.

Comment: For very small apps, would you recommend this approach over having a blueprint?

Comment: For small apps, you may not need to use app factory at all, just put everything into the `app.py`.