# Flask - avoid circular imports with app factory

Tags: python, flask

I have structured my `flask` app in such a way that an app factory unifies all `__init__.py` files into one `app` object, like so:

```
app.py
tasks.py
     /project/
             __init__.py
             routes/
                   __init__.py
                   auth_bp.py
                   register_bp.py
             models/
                   __init__.py
                   user.py
                   base.py
```

**app.py**

```
from project import create_app

app = create_app()
```

**project/__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():

    from . import routes, models

    app = Flask(__name__)
    models.init_app(app)
    routes.init_app(app)

    return app
```

**project/models/__init__,py**

```
from base import db

def init_app(app):
    db.init_app(app)
```

**project/routes/__init__.py**

```
from auth import auth_bp
from register import register_bp

def init_app(app):
    app.register_blueprint(auth_bp)
    app.register_blueprint(register_bp)
```

what I'm trying to wrap my head around is how to structure some background processes which depend on `app.context()`, like so:

**project/tasks.py**

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/root') 

from app import app

def load_cache(track_and_features):
    while True:
        with app.app_context():           
            Upload_Track(track_and_features) 

@app.route('/cache')
def cache(track_and_features):
    executor.submit(load_cache, track_and_features)
    return 'Ok'
```

the problem (I guess) occurs here, when I call `cache()`, in a module which imports the `app` object on its turn:

**project/routes/auth_bp.py**

```
from tasks import cache

@auth_bp.route("/callback/q")
def callback():
    (...)
    cache()
    return redirect(url_for('register.homepage'))
```

I am getting the error:

```
  File "app.py", line 6, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "/Users/me/Documents/Code/Apps/Production/project/__init__.py", line 20, in create_app
    from . import routes
  File "/Users/me/Documents/Code/Apps/Production/project/routes/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from auth import auth_bp
  File "/Users/me/Documents/Code/Apps/Production/project/routes/auth.py", line 18, in <module>
    from tasks import cache
  File "/Users/me/Documents/Code/Apps/Production/tasks.py", line 4, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/Users/me/Documents/Code/Apps/Production/app.py", line 6, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "/Users/me/Documents/Code/Apps/Production/project/__init__.py", line 20, in create_app
    from . import models, routes, services
ImportError: cannot import name routes
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't import `app` in `routes`. With an app factory, you *do not have an `app` to register routes with, outside of the factory*. Instead, use blueprints for all your views, and import the blueprint into the factory. You [could still register your views with the `app` object inside the factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254022/flask-are-blueprints-necessary-for-app-factories), but that's just not nearly as clean as just using a blueprint to register views with.

You already do this with dedicated `init_app()` functions, but your `project/routes/tasks.py` module doesn't follow this pattern. It too should be using a blueprint. You can share a blueprint between modules, if that simplifies your application.

The only point you actually create an `app` name, is to run the whole app, so for the WSGI server, tests or command-line tools.